# Rails BestInPlace Does it work with mobile?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, best-in-place

Dearest stackians, I've launched my app and best_in_place works great on my computer however it doesn't seem to load at all on my phone(iphone 6).  Is it not compatible with safari?  I couldn't find anything about mobile compatibility in the docs anywhere and am about to switch to X-editable to give that a shot instead since it will need to be used on mobile.  If anyone happens to know I'd appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

I know the question is old, but I just had the same problem and I assume others will have it in future, too. A quick fix for me was adding the following code in application.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".best_in_place").on("click",function(){}); 
});
```

Seems weird but works!